# Duplicates in object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**EDITED!!**

I have an object `array`:

```
Array 0:[{id:"a1" , code:"123" , name:"a"},
         {id: "a2", code: "222" , name: "a"},
          {id: "b1", code: "433", name: "b"}]
Array 1:[{id:"a1" , code:"123" , name:"a"},
         {id: "b2", code: "211" , name: "b"},
          {id: "b1", code: "433", name: "b"}]
```

I want to get the array of object that has no duplicate value for "name". and store it to another `array`:

```
Result:
Array 0:{id: "b1", code: "433", name:"b"}
Array 1: {id:"a1" , code:"123" , name:"a"}
```

How can I get the array of object that has no duplicate value for `name` ?
All I found on some thread is to remove duplicates from array and not get the array with no duplicate. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function filterByName(array) {
    var counts = {};

    array.forEach(function(obj) { 
        counts[obj.name] ? ++counts[obj.name] : (counts[obj.name] = 1);
    });

    return array.filter(function(obj) { 
        return counts[obj.name] === 1;
    });
}

var filteredArray1 = filterByName(array1);
var filteredArray2 = filterByName(array2);
```

**Explanation of function**

1. Create temporary `counts` object for keeping counts of object with the same name.
2. Fill this object with data by using standard [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method of array.
3. Filter array by using standard [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

**UPD**
    You need this if I understand your question correctly at last:

```
var filteredArray = arrayOfArrays.map(function(arrayOfObjects) {
  return filterByName(arrayOfObjects)[0];
});
```

Comment: can you explain this sir?

Comment: there's an error that says 'Invalid left-hand side in assignment' for the line  `return !temp[obj.name] && temp[obj.name] = true;`

Comment: @LewJasonNuyda: Operator precedence. Use `return !temp[obj.name] && (temp[obj.name] = true);` instead.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I forget about precedence

Comment: @FelixKling Done, explanation is added.

Comment: appreciated all your answer... when I tried `console.log(temp)` all I got are ` Object {a: true, b: true}` what I need is only the array value that has no duplicate for object `name`

Comment: @alexpods for `array` should I use my `array` ? what should I check for the result?

Comment: i forgot to tell you. that those array object from my example was only a single array that needs to be compare. meaning there is next array set that have the same array objects.

Comment: @LewJasonNuyda Update the answer. Using `filterByName` function you can filter as many arrays as you want.

Comment: @alexpods No, you don't get what I need. Let me explain, I have an array for each array, I have 3 array objects and I should get the array objects that has distinct name value.